# Stop/Abort Request when request its aborted

Tags: node.js, keep-alive, restify

I'm using Restify module for NodeJS.

Maybe it's some problem of KeepAlive, but i want abort or stop all internal process of my REST service when a user cancel the request to my API. For example when in Postman you are making a request that consume 30 seconds but you want cancel it at second 10... I want stop the process in server.

Any idea? How I need implement it?

Thanks.